# How can I get my language selector to work

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so I have been trying to make a little selector for languages for a website and I can not seem to be able to get it to work. Here is the code :

```
<select
                id="language-switcher"
                value={l10n.currentLanguage}
                onSelect={(_) => {
                  window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(
                    `/${l10n.currentLanguage}`,
                    (document.getElementById('language-switcher') as any).value
                  )
                }}
              >
                {l10n.availableLanguages.map((lang) => (
                  <option value={lang}>
                    {l10n.hydrate('LANGUAGE_DISPLAY_NAME', { lang })}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
```

I am unsure why this is not working. Thank you for reading my post!

Comment: You should use the onChange function instead as use the value from it like `onChange={(e)=>{const value = e.target.value; //do something with value}}`

Comment: I am really sorry but I am new to react and I am a bit confused. Would I use this instead of onSelect?

Comment: Yes you would replace it with ``` onChange={(e) => {
                  const value = e.target.value;
                  window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(
                    `/${l10n.currentLanguage}`,
                    value
                  )
                }}```

Comment: I tried to do that and it did not work here is what I wrote
```
<select
                id="language-switcher"
                value={l10n.currentLanguage}
                onChange={(e) => { const value = e.target.value; window.location.href = window.location.href.replace( /${l10n.currentLanguage}, value ) }}
              >
                {l10n.availableLanguages.map((lang) => (
                  <option value={lang}>
                    {l10n.hydrate('LANGUAGE_DISPLAY_NAME', { lang })}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
```

Comment: What happened? can you console.log the window.location.href.replace( /${l10n.currentLanguage}, value ) inside the onChange to see if it is correct

Comment: I am using next js and the site won't load and it says there is an error on the line where `onChange={(e) => { const value = e.target.value; window.location.href = window.location.href.replace( /${l10n.currentLanguage}, value ) }}` is

Comment: I guess the backticks surrounding the /${l10n.currentLanguage} got removed. Add them if not present

Comment: Ok thanks it still is not working though it says when I use the language selector and click a language `SyntaxError: Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': 'http://localhost:3000es' is not a valid URL.`. I am guessing this means I need to add a slash some where

Comment: It is now working! Thank you for your help